# Text in Ubuntu Software Center is unreadable

Tags: software-center, themes, fonts

When I do a search in the software center this is what the results look like.

[image]

I can only see the text if I select one of them.

I tried changing themes but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a problem with your font. If you are using Gnome Shell, install Gnome Tweak Tool, a customization tool for Gnome Shell, with the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`, launch it, and change your font from there. If you are using Unity, install Myunity, a Unity customization tool, with the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myunity/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

Then, launch Myunity and change your font from it.

Comment: It seems that there are different types of themes for different parts of the GUI. I was assuming there was only one, like in Windows. I fixed the problem by using gnome-tweak-tool to change the GTK+ theme.

Comment: gnome-tweak-tool was already installed on my system, but gnome-do did not recognize the command and it's not in the Applications menu. How can I add it there?

Comment: nvm, it's in System Tools->Preferences->Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 13):

I copy the answer from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1913590):

> I know a number of people have trouble using dark themes with Ubuntu
>   because the software center likes to keep its white background and
>   also use the default light colored text. The following solution is
>   pretty hack-tastic and I'm hoping to hear some more elegant ideas.
>
> 1. Open up a terminal and type:
>
>    ```
>    gksudo gedit /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.css
>    ```
> 2. The first two lines should look like this:
>
>    ```
>    @define-color light-aubergine #DED7DB;
>    @define-color super-light-aubergine #F4F1F3;
>    ```
>
>    Copy and paste those two lines right below then comment out the
>      originals. Change the two HTML color codes (`#DED7DB` and `#F4F1F3`)
>      to your preferred dark colors so that light text will show up.
> 3. Save and close gedit. Launch Ubuntu Software Center to check out the results

Answer (score 6):

To summarize, do what tnq177 said and change both RGB values to #333 (they don't need to be #333333).

This is an issue that should have been resolved for ages in Ubuntu Gnome/Gnome Remix. Fine tuning is not the strong point of the Gnome 3 project ....